Double factorial power series closed form expression
I have the power series
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k!!}
$$
Now, the even terms can be summed into something like $e^{z^2/2}$, given that $(2k)!! = 2^k k!$. I am aware of the expression
$$
(2k-1)!! = \frac{(2k)!}{2^k k!},
$$
but I can't quite figure out a closed form expression for the series over the odd terms, which would be necessary to find a closed form of the whole sum. Are there known results for this? For either the full series or just
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^{2k-1}}{(2k-1)!!}?
$$
If not, are there some things one can say about the asymptotic behaviour of the odd part? e.g. that it is exponential like the even part?

WolframAlpha's answer.

Note that the function $$f(z) = \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!!}$$ satisfies to the following inhomogeneous first-order linear ODE :
$$
f'(z) = 1 + \sum_{k=\color{red}{1}}^\infty \frac{z^{2k}}{(2k-1)!!} = 1 + zf(z),
$$
together with the initial condition $f(0) = 0$. It can be solved by the method of variation of parameters, hence
$$
f(z) = e^{\frac{1}{2}z^2} \int_0^z e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2} \mathrm{d}t,
$$
where the integral corresponds to the error function up to normalization.
It is to be noted too that the same developments could have been applied to the original power series, whose even-powered terms turn out to be the homogeneous solution to the same differential equation (with another initial condition nevertheless).

Usually, in applying series solutions to second order ordinary differential equations, we arrive at a solution with two series (one for each linearly independent solution)
$$C_1y_1(x) + C_2y_2(x)=C_1\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^k+C_2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}b_kx^k $$
However, this arose from applying simply the single guessed solution form $y=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}C_kx^k$ rather than two separate things. The two linearly independent solutions usually come from separation of the coefficients $C_k$ into terms containing $C_0$ and those containing $C_1$ (since they are usually recursively defined and the coefficients $C_0$ and $C_1$ are determined from initial conditions). That is, two independent series will then arise which are the two linearly independent solutions.
From your problem, we have
$$y_1(x)=e^{x^2/2} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2k}}{2^kk!}$$
We are interested in finding the differential equation this solves. Namely,
$$y(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!!}=C_1\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2k}}{2^kk!}+C_2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2k-1}}{(2k-1)!!}$$
Taking derivatives, it is easy to see that $y_1(x)=e^{x^2/2}$ solves
$$y''(x)-xy'-y=0 $$
So, if we can somehow generate the second linearly independent solution $y_2(x)$ using another non-series method, we can obtain the "closed-form" of your above series. Consider the reduction of order method by assuming:
$$y_2(x)=A(x)y_1(x)$$
Substituting into the differential equation above, we have (after many terms vanish due to the nature of $y_1(x)$ solving the ODE)
$$A''(x)y_1(x)+2A'(x)y_1(x)-xA'(x)y_1(x)=0 $$
This is first-order in $A'(x)$. Applying standard methods it is easy to show $A'(x)=Ce^{-x^2/2}$, where C is some constant of integration. Then, we clearly have
$$A(x)=C \int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^2/2}dt$$
For brevity, take $C=1$ and then after the substitution $u=t/\sqrt{2}$, we have
$$A(x)=\sqrt{2}\int_{0}^{x/\sqrt{2}}e^{-u^2}du=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\text{erf}\Bigg(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\Bigg)$$
Where the mysterious $\sqrt{\pi}$ comes from the normalization used in the common definition of the error function "erf$(x)$." It comes into play in the area under the bell-curve in probability where it is desirable to normalize this to a value of 1. Regardless, it is now clear the series you are interested in has "closed form"
$$y_2(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2k-1}}{(2k-1)!!}=e^{x^2/2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\text{erf}\Bigg(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\Bigg)$$
I'm sure you could have instead just played around with the series in question until series expansions of "known" functions appeared from which you could arrive at the error function as well. However, whether or not this is a "closed-form" is really just dependent on what you consider the error function to be. If you are looking for a form that involves only elementary functions (exponentials, polynomials, rational, root, trigonometric, logarithms, etc.), then that is not possible as the error function is well documented to be non-elementary.
One can quickly check the validity of this result by numerically matching the series expansion above with the expression involving the error function and seeing that they match. So finally, the "whole sum" you are looking for is simply
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!!} = e^{x^2/2}\Bigg[1+\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\text{erf}\Bigg(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\Bigg)\Bigg]$$
Again, there may be a more elegant way of arriving here, but this was a fun exercise nonetheless.

$$k!!=2^{\frac{1}{4} \left(2 k-(-1)^k+1\right)}\, \, \pi
   ^{\frac{1}{4} \left((-1)^k-1\right)} \Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}+1\right)$$
$$k!!=2^{k/2}\, \Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}+1\right)\,\sqrt[4]{\left(\frac{2}{\pi }\right)^{1-(-1)^k} }$$ Just by curiosity, have a look at the corresponding exponential generating function (sequence $A006882$ ins $OEIS$) which is used from the next.
Computing
$$S_p=\sum_{k=0}^p \frac {z^k}{k!!}=e^{\frac{z^2}{2}} \left(1+\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}
   \text{erf}\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)-$$
$$\frac z p\,\exp\Bigg(-\frac{p}{2} \log \left(\frac{p}{e z^2}\right)  \Bigg)\,\sqrt[4]{2^{-1-(-1)^p} \pi ^{(-1)^p-1} }$$
Using $p=25$ and $z=2$, this gives
$$e^2 \left(1+\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}
   \text{erf}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)\right)-\frac{2 e^{-\frac{25}{2} \left(\log
   \left(\frac{25}{4}\right)-1\right)}}{25\sqrt{\pi }}$$ which is $\color{red}{16.228493}98$
